# Copy user data into custom table on user registration

Tags: php, registration, sql

upon creating a user in joomla i would need fields copied from jmla_users table to another jmla_new_users.

jml_users - jmla_new_users

with the following fields, (username,firstname,lastname,email)

Also i have no clue where i would add this in the joomla registration.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If Alexandr's answer solves your issue, please award his answer the green tick.  If you are seeking a different approach, please explain what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create plugin with user [onUserAfterSave](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterSave) function and put users data in whichever table you need

You can see example in /plugins/user/profile/profile.php